# Why does this Objective-C message make a hash?

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading the open source of a library and I notice this method—hash.

```
-(NSUInteger)hash:(NSObject*)targetObject
{
    return (NSUInteger)targetObject;
}
```

Why would this be the hash?

Comment: 1. That's not the correct signature of the `hash` method of `NSObject`. 2. You have not provided any context. What is `targetObject`?

Comment: @Maddy - yup. It's not the correct `hash` method of `NSObject` because it was in a 3rd party library. I added the `targetObject` parameter I forgot to type because I captured the spirit of the class in which this was in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target is a pointer to an object. That means it's an integer and you can definitely convert it to a `NSUInteger`.

It basically means that two distinct instances of a class will always have a different hash. That's probably a valid solution if `isEqual` is defined in terms of reference equality.

The default implementation of `[NSObject hash]` actually returns `self`.